# Get value from other .tex without \input

Tags: variable

I create a PDF document with pdflatex by attaching several `.tex` files with `\input` to each other through a loop. Now I would like to introduce a boolean in the single `.tex` files. Depending on whether true or false a different header should be used. However, I don't know how to get the value without having already imported the `.tex`.

**EDIT:**

Here a minimal example:

example.tex

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm,top=0.8cm,right=2cm,bottom=3.3cm,headheight=61pt, footskip=61pt, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\definecolor{accentcolor}{HTML}{66cc33}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \lhead{\LARGE{{\normalfont\MakeUppercase Details}\\\textcolor{accentcolor}{\Large Test}}}
  \rhead{right side}
}
\pagestyle{plain} % 
 
\newboolean{projectHighlight}
%#####################################################################################################################################################
\begin{document}

\input{details_file}

%all projects from folder desc.:

\let\mylist\empty
\foreach\x in {00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, ...,99} {
  \ifx\mylist\empty
    \xdef\mylist{\x}%
  \else
    \xdef\mylist{\x,\mylist}%
  \fi
}
\foreach\x in \mylist {%    The % here are necessary to eliminate any spurious spaces that may get inserted at these points
    \edef\projectNumber{\x}%
    \edef\FileName{project_\x}%     
    \IfFileExists{\FileName}{%  
       \newpage%
       \input{\FileName}%
       \ifthenelse{\boolean{projectHighlight}}{\lhead{\LARGE{{\normalfont\MakeUppercase Highlited}\\\textcolor{accentcolor}{\Large Test}}}}
       {\lhead{\LARGE{{\normalfont\MakeUppercase Not Highlihhted}\\\textcolor{accentcolor}{\Large Test}}}}       
    }
}
\end{document}
```

details_file.tex

```
some details
```

project_01.tex

```
\setboolean{projectHighlight}{true}

Text first project
```

project_2.tex

```
\setboolean{projectHighlight}{true}

Text second project
```

Comment: you can't in general but why can't you input the files then add the header when you get to the boolean?  Questions are always clearer if you provide a small but complete test case

Comment: You could _parse_ the `.tex` file to look for the line ....

Comment: I updated my question with an example. If I try to put the line to override the header after \input nothing happens.

Comment: For me it would be enough just to check the first line. How can I parse it?